# Redirect console input to pipe in c

Tags: c, pipe, stdin

I want a functionality similar with:

`cat >&5`
where 5 is the pipe fd

but in c.

Is there an elegant way to achieve that or do i have to read the stdin to a buffer and write it to the pipe (or just execute the above command)?

```
int fd[2];
pipe(fd);

...
... (fork)
... kid is reading from fd[0]

//Parent:
//method 1
char line[255];
int got;
while((got=read(0, line, 255))>0){
    write(fd[1], line, got);
} 
//method 2
char cmd[25];
snprintf(cmd, 25, "cat >&%d", fd[1]);
system(cmd);
```

Both methods work, I just wondered if there is a better way for the task...

Comment: Please provide more information about the use case. How do expect to know file descriptor values from the "outside" of a program?

Comment: Have you tried the solution you mention and if so, where is the code you wrote for it?

Comment: When the shell processes the command you present, it spawns a subshell, in that subshell dupes file descriptor 5 onto the standard output and standard error file descriptors, and finally execs the `cat` command in the subshell.  You can do any or all of that in a C program (which the shell *is*, after all).  Be aware, however, that reading into a buffer and writing the data back out is a necessary component any way around; in your shell command that's just hidden inside `cat`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: With `>&5` I think the shell duplicates standard output onto file descriptor 5, rather than vice versa — which I think is just a disconnect between what you meant and what you said.  I agree with you that some process somewhere is going to have to read standard input ('the console') and write what it reads to the pipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here are a summary of the ways I managed to do it:

```
//Parent:
//method 1
char line[255];
int got;
while((got=read(0, line, 255))>0){
    write(fd[1], line, got);
} 

//method 2
char cmd[25];
snprintf(cmd, 25, "cat >&%d", fd[1]);
system(cmd);

//method 3
while (1) splice(0, NULL, fd[1], NULL, 255, 0);
```

All methods could possibly be in another thread to let parent continue.

I have added splice as well which does seem to do exactly what we are looking for.